# I am making a program on python that detects if the user is wearing a face mask?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
# USAGE
# python detect_mask_video.py

# import the necessary packages
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os

def detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet):
    # grab the dimensions of the frame and then construct a blob
    # from it
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (300, 300),
        (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

    # pass the blob through the network and obtain the face detections
    faceNet.setInput(blob)
    detections = faceNet.forward()

    # initialize our list of faces, their corresponding locations,
    # and the list of predictions from our face mask network
    faces = []
    locs = []
    preds = []

    # loop over the detections
    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with
        # the detection
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        # filter out weak detections by ensuring the confidence is
        # greater than the minimum confidence
        if confidence > args["confidence"]:
            # compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for
            # the object
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            # ensure the bounding boxes fall within the dimensions of
            # the frame
            (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
            (endX, endY) = (min(w - 1, endX), min(h - 1, endY))

            # extract the face ROI, convert it from BGR to RGB channel
            # ordering, resize it to 224x224, and preprocess it
            face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
            face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
            face = img_to_array(face)
            face = preprocess_input(face)
            face = np.expand_dims(face, axis=0)

            # add the face and bounding boxes to their respective
            # lists
            faces.append(face)
            locs.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))

    # only make a predictions if at least one face was detected
    if len(faces) > 0:
        # for faster inference we'll make batch predictions on *all*
        # faces at the same time rather than one-by-one predictions
        # in the above `for` loop
        preds = maskNet.predict(faces)

    # return a 2-tuple of the face locations and their corresponding
    # locations
    return (locs, preds)

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-f", "--face", type=str,
    default="face_detector",
    help="path to face detector model directory")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", type=str,
    default="mask_detector.model",
    help="path to trained face mask detector model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load our serialized face detector model from disk
print("[INFO] loading face detector model...")
prototxtPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"], "deploy.prototxt"])
weightsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"],
    "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"])
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

# load the face mask detector model from disk
print("[INFO] loading face mask detector model...")
maskNet = load_model(args["model"])

# initialize the video stream and allow the camera sensor to warm up
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
time.sleep(2.0)

# loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:
    # grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
    # to have a maximum width of 400 pixels
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)

    # detect faces in the frame and determine if they are wearing a
    # face mask or not
    (locs, preds) = detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet)

    # loop over the detected face locations and their corresponding
    # locations
    for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
        # unpack the bounding box and predictions
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
        (mask, withoutMask) = pred

        # determine the class label and color we'll use to draw
        # the bounding box and text
        label = "Mask" if mask > withoutMask else "No Mask"
        color = (0, 255, 0) if label == "Mask" else (0, 0, 255)

        # include the probability in the label
        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(mask, withoutMask) * 100)

        # display the label and bounding box rectangle on the output
        # frame
        cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)

    # show the output frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# do a bit of cleanup
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

The code runs through without any errors, but it doesn't start the webcam. What should I do so that it actually starts the webcam and tells me if I am wearing mask or not? This is coded in python on idle on a MacBook Pro, late 2015 model.

[image: This is what it does. Then it ends the code.]

Comment: Can somebody PLEASE reply ASAP. My team and I really need to figure this out by tonight. Thank you so much!

Comment: The code seems fine. Try debugging one by one. Trying printing the frame after receiving it from the video source. If you don't see anything, check your webcam is disabled or not. But if you find the frame there, that means it's stuck on the very first frame. In that case, you can check whether your prediction function is stuck somewhere or not.

Comment: If I run it from terminal, I get this error:                   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect_mask_video.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
ImportError: No module named tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2
ParthDama1@Parths-MBP face-mask-detector %

Comment: do you have everything installed properly? please run 'pip list' and check if everything you imported is in the list. If not, install by using 'pip install x', replace x with your prefered library. 'pip install tensorflow' for example. if you already have installed TensorFlow, downgrade it to 1.14 and check again.

Comment: Tried it. Still giving the same error.

Comment: Can I see pip list output?

Comment: Any chance there is an anti-virus software preventing access to the webcam?